# Compute difference between list-of-dicts, return dict with new keys and old values

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, nested

I want to map the differences between two lists of dictionaries.

I am using Python 3.5, and want to know the best way to get differences between sets. I am aware of set operations, but I am not sure if this is the best way to implement them in my current situation.

Here is what I have now:

```
orig = set()
chng = set()

original = [{"name": "Tom Pety", "name_id": 1}, {"name": "Tom Cruz", "name_id": 2}]
changed = [{"name": "Tom Petty"}, {"name": "Tom Cruise"}]

for item in original:
    orig.update(item.values())

for item in changed:
    chng.update(item.values())

diffs = orig - chng
```

My current output is `{'Tom Pety', 1, 2, 'Tom Cruz'}`.

Ultimately, what I would like to get a result that looks like this, so that the values which changed are associated to their id:

`[{"name": "Tom Petty", "name_id": 1}, {"name": "Tom Cruise", "name_id": 2}]`

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Do the `original` and the `changed` list have the same order?

Comment: I don't understand what you're doing. Your desired output is the same as your original input.

Comment: @DanielRoseman: no, check the spelling of the names.

Comment: I don't follow: the `name_id` fields didn't change, but you're listing them in your output.

Comment: @Prune: these changed, he wants to calculate the updates through the `original` list.

Comment: What does this have to do with sets?

Comment: @StefanPochmann - I was not sure if perhaps `set` was the best way to go about this to get the differences, or if I was barking up the wrong tree so to speak.

Comment: You're actually using nested lists-of-dicts. They're not sets. `orig = set()` is a red herring, you overwrite it with a list-of-dicts. (see also NamedTuple). It helps if you tell us more context: are you trying to process JSON, or store these into objects...

Comment: When dealing with dicts, try to use the standard terms `keys` and `values`. And a set is merely a dict which only has keys, but no values. But you don't want a set here, because you have values as well as keys. So you want a list-of-dicts (or dict-of-dicts, or set-of-NamedTuple, or whatever). In any case, some nested data structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the **lists have the same order** (this means that the *first* item of `changed` has to be applied to the *first* item of `original`, etc.), then we can use `zip` to iterate over the lists concurrently, and use the `dict.update` function to update these concurrently. Like:

```
for orig, chang in zip(original, changed):
    orig.update(chang)
```

after this, the `orig` list will contain a list with the dictionaries:

```
>>> original
[{'name': 'Tom Petty', 'name_id': 1}, {'name': 'Tom Cruise', 'name_id': 2}]
```

Note that we *update* the dictionaries, we do *not* construct new ones. In case we need to create new ones, we can for instance use the following approach:

```
new_list = [ {**orig, **chang} for orig, chang in zip(original, changed) ]
```

This syntax for dictionaries has been introduced in [**PEP-448**](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/), and is *not* supported in [python-2.x](/questions/tagged/python-2.x), and [python-3.x](/questions/tagged/python-3.x) up to (but without) 3.5.

Comment: For the example above, I am assuming the lists are ordered properly. If they were not ordered properly, I understand that finding the differences would be much more difficult?

Comment: @unseen_damage: the problem is that it becomes very vague what a fix is. Say you have in `original = [{'name': 'Leonardo'}]` and in `changed = [{'name': 'Leonardo Da Vinci'}, {'name': 'Leonardo DiCaprio'}]` what one to pick? Furthermore how do we know that the original one was incorrect? Based on what measure we decide what fix is the best one? There is no correct answer for that.

Comment: What would you suggest in this case? Notice the `address_country` changed, and I am not getting the output desired:
`original = [{'postal_code': '85043', 'address_id': 1, 'state': 'AZ', 'address': '123 my road', 'city': 'PHONEIX', 'address_country': None}]` and 
`changed = [{'postal_code': '85043', 'city': 'PHONEIX', 'address_country': 'United States of America', 'state': 'AZ', 'address': '123 my road'}]`

 My output looks like the following:
`new list [{'address_id': 1, 'address_country': None, 'state': 'AZ', 'address': '123 my road', 'postal_code': '85043', 'city': 'PHONEIX'}]`

Comment: I got (with both methods `[{'city': 'PHONEIX', 'address_id': 1, 'address_country': 'United States of America', 'address': '3037 S. 69TH DRIVE', 'postal_code': '85043', 'state': 'AZ'}]`).